# Can't find the .pbxproj file in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem regarding my .pbxproj file. I worked on a Xcode project on one computer and then I cloned it using SourceTree on another computer. But now I can't open the project since the project.pbxproj file is completely gone. I haven't added it to my .gitignore file and when I worked on the project on the other computer I have never had any problems.

So why have it disappeared and is there a way to get it back? I can't find it at all in my source code. Not even if I revert back to my initial commit. Can it be that when I pushed the projects source code to bit bucket my .pbxproj file wasn't committed?

Is there a way to create a new .pbxproj file? I don't have the computer with the working project here, it's in my office.

**Edit:**
Including my `.gitignore` file

```
# OS X Finder
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
#
#Pods/
```

Comment: Did you check the (initial) commit, that it was actually included in the commit? Sounds like it wasn't.

Comment: No it seems like it has not been committed. But why is that? Why didn't the .pbxproj file get committed? Seems weird since I pushed the whole project to the repo without doing anything that could have removed the .pbxproj file @d4Rk

Comment: Normally it should be included inside the `.xcodeproj` file/package, is this completely missing, or just the `.pbxproj` file? Maybe you can also provide your `.gitignore`, just to be sure. Anyway, I'm afraid you'll have to set up a new project, and then add all your existing files.

Comment: It's just the .pbxproj file that's missing. I've updated my question to include my .gitignore @d4Rk

Comment: The `.gitignore` looks ok for me. Is it possible, that you just forgot/missed to commit it?

Comment: I guess that's the issue, the file just isn't committed. Just so annoying.. @d4Rk

Comment: Sorry, but I think there's nothing I can do for you. Maybe you can get access to the machine, where you pushed it from? Or ask someone that has access to it?

Comment: I'll get access to it on Monday :) Just asked here if there was a way to recreate it. Thank you @d4Rk

Comment: @d4Rk Today I tried creating a new Xcode project and push it to a new repository. I pushed the entire Xcode project without a .gitignore to the repo and then I cloned it on another computer and still the project.pbxproj file isn't commited and pushed to the repo. I can't seem to get it to be pushed with all the other files. Do you have any idea why? I just don't get it why that file is automatically ignored when I push my project to my repo.

Comment: Sounds really strange, there seem to be other ways too, to ignore files: check this out: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/
Another possibility is, sparse-checkout, which filters files, for the checkout (but thats off by default, so I don't think thats the case for you)

Comment: @d4Rk I managed to solve it, se my own answer to this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this was a major D'oh! moment and my own misstake. I found that I had a global `.gitignore` file on the computer. And in that file I for some reson had added the `project.pbxproj`

So now it works. Stupid stupid stupid...

Answer (score -1):

1. $defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
2. Show in finder
3. Open the circled file and delete the row contains project.pbxproj
   [image]